# What does DMA Channel virtualization mean?

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, dma, mmu

Hi I have seen documents in which DMA is working on the **physical addresses**. In that  The DMA controller is actually using physical address to access the FIFOs. In a recent discussion a question came up that when we implement a driver for DMA whether this will work on physical address or virtual address. In the discussion the term **DMA Channel virtualization** also came up. Does this have anything to do with **Virtual addressing** as such. or DMA does not use virtual addressing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many devices these days come with iommu. This allows the paltform to create a virtual address space for the peripheral bus. This can be used for virtalization and is also useful for DMA when copying a large set of scattered memory pages without supporting scatter gather.